# improve perfomance in chat application

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, yii

i've made a chat application for my friends (programmers as well) in order to pass codes and links between us, but after some messages sent, the chat seems to be taking so long to send a message and load the log when the user enters the chat when a new session is created, im using wamp for hosting, yii for php framework and jquery for javascript framework, im also using mysql for user and chat storage, i dont know why it sometimes takes long to load even for the same server, maybe is because im sending the chat log in arrays from php, here is how i recieve it:

```
<?php foreach ($chat as $data): ?>
    <?php if($data->Text == 'disconnected'): ?>
        <i><strong><?php echo $data->users->username; ?></strong> <?php echo $data->Text; ?></i>
        <br/>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($data->Text != 'disconnected'): ?>
        <strong>(<?php echo $data->time; ?>) <?php echo $data->users->username; ?>:</strong> <?php CheckLink($data->Text); ?>
        <br/>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

here is how yii controller is rendering it:

```
public function actionAjaxscript()
    {
        $chat = Chat::model()->findAll();
        if(isset($_POST["usermsg"])){
            echo "hello";
        }

        $this->renderPartial('_ajax', array('chat'=>$chat));
    }
```

im sending this because i think the problem comes from here, does anyone know how this can be fixed?. if you need to see the other codes, please let me know and ill show them.

Comment: Every time you hit the button you fetch all the conversation instead of just the new messages....that can be fixed

Comment: alright, ill try to change the code to get only new messages instead all of them, thank you

Comment: Then you just append the new messages

Comment: Really shouldn't be using MySql for a chat system these days! Should go with Node.js and Socket.io

Comment: i was thinking about sqlite, or some database system thats fast

Comment: @mario - true, since node.js and socket.io are persistent storage. Oh, wait..

Comment: @N.B. Just add in MongoDB or similar NoSql solution!

Comment: @mario - why? Do you actually have **any** factual and accurate explanation **why** one shouldn't use MySQL + PHP for a chat app made for himself and his friends? And please, without links to blogs that measure hello world apps on node.js and php+apache which are as accurate as blind men shooting with crossbow for an apple.

Comment: @N.B. This isn't the place to have this conversation, he wanted a faster system and I suggested a different solution in the comment section. I'm not stopping anyone from posting a good answer in php+mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your approach is the best.

You are loading every time the entire chat history, you should only be loading the new lines, not everything each time. Each time when you open a page have a hash created. That page should always ask for new lines using that particular hash. The server knows what he last sent to that hash and can only send new messages (not all of them again). Try using json to send the chat messages back instead of the entire html structure, that will also speed it up.

MySQL will soon become overwhelmed by chat requests if you have a lot of users, try improving it by using memcache or APC to cache the chat lines for faster access.

If you are performing some sort of jquery after the chat lines are shown then the browser itself might slow down. Scroll up and down to see if it is slowed. It happened to me after adding 50 products to a shopping cart.

Also you have 2 IF commands in the view, why not have an else? It would work exactly the same and it will put less stress on the server.

Also in your example you are not sending the data as arrays, you are sending it as html.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple ajax based solution:

On initial load, send limited history. (last X messages).

Keep track of the date of the last message, per user. session variable or such.

Poll for messages newer than that date, appending to existing content.  I use jQuery like this:

```
$("#messages").append("New content.");
```

Update last message date.  Rinse, repeat.